# Java - Issues with reading a file into an array and using the array afterwards

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I made a class that reads a text file into an integer array, which I believe I've done correctly. Then I wanted to make a method ***(getInt();)*** within that to get the the first index of the array, and then each time it gets called get the following index element.

I had the idea to increment it every time it gets called to get the following index element, but the main problem I am having is that I cannot access my list outside of the try statement and I am therefore unable to make a method for it.

Can anyone suggest a piece of code or any advice on how to create this method?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ScannerIntegerList {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         FileReader file = new FileReader("file.txt");
         BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(file);

         List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

         String temp = "";

         while ((temp = input.readLine()) != null)
            if (!temp.trim().equals("0"))
               list.add(new Integer(temp));

         input.close();

         int i = 0;
         System.out.println(list.get(i));
         i++;

      } catch (IOException ie) {
         System.out.println(ie);
      }
   }

}
```

Also as a side note I am using eclipse and whenever I try and remove public static void main( String [] args) it tells me I need it, can anyone explain why this happens and how I can get around it, specifically with this bit of code?

When this class is finished the filename will also come from the command line so any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: @ROMANIA that would not do, if he wants to print the list with `i` he needs a `for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
         System.out.println(list.get(i));
         }`

Comment: I see where I've gone wrong with that, would you know how to make a method using that though? As I can't get the list outside of the try block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `list` outside the try block, declare and initialize it outside.

Also, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when working with closeable resources, like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
    String temp = "";
    while ((temp = input.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!temp.trim().equals("0")) {
            list.add(new Integer(temp));
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// you can use list here, knock yourself out
```

If the filename will come from the command line,
then you really need the `public static void main(String[] args)` method.
Your program will receive command line arguments in the `args` array.
If the filename is the first command line argument,
you can use it via `args[0]`.